# How to force magento 2 admin to use http instead of https?

Tags: magento, magento2

I have enabled SSL and both frontend and admin working fine in SSL mode.

Now, I want to force admin to use only http.

I have disabled "web/secure/use_in_adminhtml". But now getting too many redirects and admin website is not accessible.

Cleared magento cache and still not able to access.

Config: Magento 2.1.7, nginx, varnish, redis